# Does .Net Standard Library supports Windows7 WPF Application?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am planning to write a cross-platform library that should run on Xamarin, UWP and WPF application targeting Windows 7? From the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) Windows7 was never mentioned. Does that mean I can't use my library in Windows7 even though WPF application is built on the latest .Net framework (4.6)?  Does that mean there is an OS dependency also in addition to .Net framework?

thanks !

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Your library can be used with a WPF program. But .NET Standard does not include any UI frameworks, so .NET Core (which implements .NET Standard only) can't run a WPF program. In other words, you can use your library on the desktop OS, but you can't run your desktop program on a non-desktop OS. What is it that _you're_ trying to do?

Comment: That is a bit confusing, Microsoft marketing names always are.  Where it says "Windows" in the chart they are actually talking about WinRT.  The api that you use to create apps that can be sold through the Store, it was first released in Win8.  It is called UWP since Windows 10.  Don't worry about targeting it, most anybody that had Win8 or 8.1 updated their machines to Win10 so can run a UWP app.  For the WPF app you only worry about the desktop version of .NET, 3rd and 4th row in the chart.

Comment: Thanks !  Win8 term confused me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use your library in .NET Framework project.
But if you will use .NET Framework 4.6 max you cannot use versions of .NET Standard above 1.3. If you target your library to higher version of .NET Standard it will be impossible to run/compile app at machine with .NET Framework 4.6.

Microsoft says (its from your link):

> In general, we recommend you to target the lowest version of .NET Standard possible.

but older version of .NET Standard have a poorer collection of methods and packages.

So it is possible if you target .NET Standard in version 1.3 or below.